# how can I transform the data from rows and columns to tabular form by using excel or python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, powerbi

how can I transform the data from A to B by using excel or python?

A

```
Column A     Column B      Column C       Column D        Column E
Jack          Micheal      16/02/2021     medicine A     medicine B
```

B

```
Column A      Column B          Column C
Jack          16/02/2021       medicine A
Jack          16/02/2021       medicine B
Micheal       16/02/2021       medicine A
Micheal       16/02/2021       medicine B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel you could use Power Query for this by following these steps, which assume the data is in A1:E2 on Sheet1.

### Get data into Power Query

1. Select the data.
2. Go to Data>Get & Transform Data...
3. Select From Table/Range.

### Transform data in Power Query

1. Select Column A and column B, go to Transform tab and select Unpivot columns.
2. Right click the Attribute column header and select Remove.
3. Select the Value and Column C columns, go to Transform tab and select Unpivot Other columns.
4. Repeat step 2

You should now have the data you want and you can rename/move the columns as required.

Once you have everything as you want it click Close & Load to return the code to Excel.

This is the [M-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/) generated by those steps.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", type text}, {"Column C", type datetime}, {"Column D", type text}, {"Column E", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column C", "Column D", "Column E"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Value", "Column C", "Column D", "Column E"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Reordered Columns", {"Value", "Column C"}, "Attribute", "Value.1"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Value", "Colimn A"}, {"Column C", "Column B"}, {"Value.1", "Column C"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your table inputs in a list of lists structure

You can do this without importing any library by using the following code:

```py
table = [['Column A','Column B','Column C','Column D','Column E'],
         ['Jack','Micheal','16/02/2021','medicine A','medicine B']]

def print_table(table):
    longest_cols = [
        (max([len(str(row[i])) for row in table]) + 3)
        for i in range(len(table[0]))
    ]
    row_format = "".join(["{:<" + str(longest_col) + "}" for longest_col in longest_cols])
    for row in table:
        print(row_format.format(*row))
        
print_table(table)
```